word request: the noun of satisfactory
Does the adjective "satisfactory" have an equivalent noun? In the chart below, why didn't they use an adjective instead of "satisfaction"? Does "satisfaction" mean those respondents found the range of materials there satisfactory or satisfying?


Adjectives don't have "noun forms".  There are some suffixes that can form nouns from adjectives, but you can't always assume that the word that you form like this will have any currency.

The chart needs editing in order to be satisfaction.  ;-)

For some reason the word adequate evaded the chart maker.  And the chart could have been titled Adequacy of Library Resources.

This is not genuine IELTS material. It contains elementary errors in English.

Satisfaction is an incorrect word to use; satisfactory is right, and that means the responders found the range of reading materials satisfactory, not satisfying.
Edit
By adding the suffix "ness", we can get a noun form of satisfactory, satisfactoriness,
found several pages down or here.  This, however, isn't suitable as we should use an adjective.

I would not call "satisfactoriness" the noun form of "satisfactory".  It is a noun that can be formed by adding the suffix "ness".  Adjectives don't have "Noun forms", Verbs don't have "adjective forms". The formation of "-ness" is not part of the grammar of English.

Thanks,  @James K.  I have edited my answer.
